# How to destroy / Clear an object created using applicationcontext.xml file in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, object, spring-mvc

I am creating Web application using Spring 3.2.1...

I have injected number of beans from my ApplicationContext.xml file, Its gets initialized and works fine.

Now my Issue is, I want to destroy some of those(not all object) objects created using ApplicationContext.xml manually.

Is it possible to destroy particular objects created using applicationcontext.xml file? If so please let me know the way to achieve it..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why do you need to do that? What is your main requirement, I believe you are doing the wrong thing.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea, you probably shouldn't be using Spring to create them if you don't want them forever.

Comment: If you want to use an object for short term try using prototype scope, where spring will create the object, but will not hold reference to it, so when all the active scope references to the object is over it will get garbage collected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following snippet demonstrates how to remove a bean from the ApplicationContext.

```
ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory = context
        .getBeanFactory();

BeanDefinitionRegistry beanDefinitionRegistry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) configurableListableBeanFactory;
// Removing the bean from container
beanDefinitionRegistry.removeBeanDefinition("demo");
```

[Source](http://shinusworkspace.blogspot.com/2012/05/adding-and-removing-spring-initialized.html)

To retrieve the `ApplicationContext` from a controller simply autowire the context.

```
private @Autowired
ApplicationContext context;
```